# C# MODBUS Protocol REnogy Wanderer Rover 20A/40A Solar Charge Controller

Tags: c#, modbus

I'm trying to read MODBUS Protocol Renogy Wanderer/Rover 20A/40A  Solar Charge Controller via RS232 procotol.

Here Read register Request example:

```
Description     No. of bytes        Command
Device address      BYTE             01H to F7H
Function code       BYTE             03H
Start address       WORD             0000H to FFFFH
No. of read words   WORD             0001H to 007DH
Check code          WORD             CRC checksum of all the above bytes
```

Example of hex input to read controller's system voltage and system current (the PDU address is known to be 000AH)

```
To send: 01 03 000A 0001 A408
To receive: 01 03 02 181E 324C
```

Here the REnogy MODBUS Protocol full doc:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OSW3gluYNK8d_gSz4Bk89LMQ4ZrzjQY6/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110144688998608708274&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class ModbusRTUProtocol
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            SerialPort serialPort1 = null;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is the beginning: ");

                serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();

                serialPort1.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
                serialPort1.Open();
                    
                byte[] bytestosend = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x03, 0x000A, 0x0001, 0xA408 };


                serialPort1.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

            // read input
            string incoming = port.ReadExisting();

            Console.WriteLine(incoming);

        }
    }
```

I got an Error  CS0031  Constant value '41992' cannot be converted to a 'byte'

A408 hex value cannot be converted to a 'byte'.
How do I send hex data to SerialPort?
My problem is the A408 hex value CRC checksum is bigger than a byte.

**UPDATE:**
With your comments, I was able break data down into bytes before sending it:
{0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0xA4, 0x08}

I modified my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class ModbusRTUProtocol
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            SerialPort serialPort1 = null;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is the beginning: ");       

                byte slaveAddress = 1;
                byte function = 3;
                string hex_add = "000A";
                ushort startAddress = Convert.ToUInt16(hex_add, 16);             
                uint numberOfPoints = 1;

                Console.WriteLine("Value of hex: " + hex_add);
                Console.WriteLine("Value of ushort: " + startAddress);


                serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();

                serialPort1.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
                serialPort1.Open();

                byte[] frame = ReadHoldingRegistersMsg(slaveAddress, startAddress, function, numberOfPoints);

                foreach(var item in frame)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0:X2} ", item));
                }

                serialPort1.Write(frame, 0, frame.Length);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

            // read input
            string incoming = port.ReadExisting();

            Console.WriteLine(incoming);

        }



private static byte[] ReadHoldingRegistersMsg(byte slaveAddress, ushort startAddress, byte function, uint numberOfPoints)
        {
            byte[] frame = new byte[8];
            frame[0] = slaveAddress;                // Slave Address
            frame[1] = function;                    // Function             
            frame[2] = (byte)(startAddress >> 8);   // Starting Address High
            frame[3] = (byte)startAddress;          // Starting Address Low            
            frame[4] = (byte)(numberOfPoints >> 8); // Quantity of Registers High
            frame[5] = (byte)numberOfPoints;        // Quantity of Registers Low
            byte[] crc = CalculateCRC(frame);  // Calculate CRC.
            frame[6] = crc[0];       // Error Check Low
            frame[7] = crc[1];       // Error Check High
            return frame;
        }


 private static byte[] CalculateCRC(byte[] data)
        {
            ushort CRCFull = 0xFFFF; // Set the 16-bit register (CRC register) = FFFFH.
            byte CRCHigh = 0xFF, CRCLow = 0xFF;
            char CRCLSB;
            byte[] CRC = new byte[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < (data.Length) - 2; i++)
            {
                CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ data[i]); // 

                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    CRCLSB = (char)(CRCFull & 0x0001);
                    CRCFull = (ushort)((CRCFull >> 1) & 0x7FFF);

                    if (CRCLSB == 1)
                        CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ 0xA001);
                }
            }
            CRC[1] = CRCHigh = (byte)((CRCFull >> 8) & 0xFF);
            CRC[0] = CRCLow = (byte)(CRCFull & 0xFF);
            return CRC;
        }

}
```

Sending {0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0xA4, 0x08} still doesn't return a value...maybe it's my USB serial RS232 wire? or the way implement my code?

Comment: Have the hex values as ints and use BitConverter.GetBytes(<val>) on each one?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush I already tried it and got the same error because the hex value of A408 is bigger  255.

Comment: Wouldn't A408 / 41992 need to be sent as a word, anyway?

Comment: Yes word, but the serial port write method take byte[].  So I'm not sure how to to do that. public void Write (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);

Comment: You'll need to break your data down into bytes before sending. You can get the bytes for the int values with BitConverter.GetBytes, but the protocol probably expects network byte order, so if you're on a little-endian machine you'll have to reverse the array that comes back. As a test, you could try sending {0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0xA4, 0x08} to see if the response is what you expect.

Comment: You supposedly have to send the integer value bytewise?

Comment: I tried sending {0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0xA4, 0x08} or {0x01, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x01, 0xA4, 0x08}  with no luck! :-(

Comment: Its probably worth checking that everything is working with a known good application (e.g. [Modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html) or [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)) before trying custom code (helps ensure you have the wiring etc right).

Comment: I tried ModPoll, but still no response. I used FT231x USB UART connection to interface with the Modbus / RS232 SerialPort. Any suggestion/idea?

Comment: If you are sure your settings (baud rate etc) and wiring is correct and have tried multiple clients (with different RS-232 interfaces) then it would seem likely the issue is with the unit. I have not used this particular controller so cannot really comment further.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have TX & RX reversed.  Pin 1 of the RJ12 connector goes to TX of your computer's serial interface.  See diagram here: http://vcsco.com/uncategorized/renogy-rover-monitoring-with-the-raspberry-pi/

I wrote a C program to communicate with the Renogy Rover 20A via RJ12 and I was seeing garbage replies like "FF FF FD".  I decided to swap RX & TX lines then all of a sudden I saw correct responses Eg:

Sent: 01 03 00 0A 00 01 A4 08
Recieved: 01 03 02 18 14 b2 4b

Where:
18 = 24V
14 = 20A